# A set of formulas is satisfiable iff it logically entails no contradiction

Tags: solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Here's the problem;

A set of formulas $\Sigma$ is satisfiable iff there is no contradiction $X$ such that $\Sigma \models X$.

---

Proof Attempt:

Suppose that $\Sigma$ is satisfiable. Then, there is a truth assignment $v$ such that $v(\alpha) = T$ for every $\alpha \in \Sigma$. So, if there is a contradiction $X$ such that $\Sigma \models X$, then $v(X) = T$ and that is impossible. Hence, there cannot be a contradiction $X$ such that $\Sigma \models X$.

Now, suppose that there is no contradiction $X$ such that $\Sigma \models X$. If $\Sigma$ is not satisfiable, then for a given truth assignment $v$, there is an $\alpha \in \Sigma$ such that $v(\alpha) = F$. Define $X$ to be $(\alpha \land (\lnot \alpha))$. Then, it is clear that $\Sigma \models X$. Otherwise, there would exist a truth assignment satisfying $\Sigma$ but not satisfying $X$. That is impossible. Hence, $\Sigma$ is satisfiable. $\Box$

Does the argument above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

Comment: Bump would still not be opposed to having some feedback on this haha

Comment: Maybe the second part can be more "transparent" proving: if $\Sigma$ is **not** Sat, then it entails a contradiction". In general, if not Sat, then it entails **every** formula.

Comment: How would I show that explicitly? Like, how would I show that it entails every contradiction? I've only shown that it entails a particular contradiction but I guess that's not enough, right?

Comment: Apply the def: $\Sigma \vDash \varphi$ reads: "for every valuation $v$, if $v(\Sigma)=\text T$, then $v(\varphi)=\text T$". IF $\Sigma$ is not Sat, then there is **no** valuation such that $v(\Sigma)=\text T$. Thus, the previous def applies vacuously with $\varphi$ whatever

Comment: Ahhh I see. So, I didn't have to go through the trouble of specifying $X = (\alpha \land (\lnot \alpha))$ and then showing that $\Sigma \models X$. I could've just done that with any formula whatsoever and that would've made the argument more clear?